# Drawing NetworkX graph with Graphviz

Tags: networkx, graphviz

I'm trying to draw a "Spring Layout" type graph.
I'm able to do so with NetworkX but I get quite a messy graph that I'm unable to tidy-up.
I have a 250 branch graph, representing an electric circuit that has a loop and several radial branches.

I've read that it is possible to optimize the node placement by using Graphviz.
Indeed, it seems that NetworkX has linking functions to Graphviz, for example `nx.nx_pydot.graphviz_layout(G)`

I've tried to use it but I get the following error message:

> pos = nx.nx_pydot.graphviz_layout(G)   File
> "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_pydot.py", line
> 261, in graphviz_layout
> return pydot_layout(G=G, prog=prog, root=root, **kwds)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_pydot.py", line
> 310, in pydot_layout
> D_bytes = P.create_dot(prog=prog)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pydot.py", line 1734, in new_method
> format=f, prog=prog, encoding=encoding)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pydot.py", line 1933, in create
> raise OSError(*args) OSError: [Errno 2] "neato" not found in path.

I've duly installed both libraries and included them in my Python code by typing:

```
import networkx as nx
import graphviz as gv
```

Am I supposed to install any other library to make it work?

Any help will be wellcome.
Thanks.

Eneko.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was solved by adding `import pydot` and setting the node position with `pos = nx.nx_pydot.graphviz_layout(G,prog,root)`
Indeed, it works either way with the following `pos = nx.nx_pydot.pydot_layout(G)`

Finally, my code looks like the following:

```py
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_weighted_edges_from(BranchList)
prog = 'neato'
root = None
# pos = nx.nx_pydot.graphviz_layout(G,prog,root)
pos = nx.nx_pydot.pydot_layout(G)
plt.figure()    
nx.draw(G,pos,edge_color='black',width=1,linewidths=1, node_size=10,node_color='blue',alpha=0.9)
plt.axis('on')
plt.show()
```

Note that I keep one of the two possible node positioning `pos=` solutions as a commented row.

Cheers.
Eneko